# trying to push changes from one branch to another with rebase and I'm not understanding it

Tags: git

I have two branches:

- master
- deploy

when something gets pushed in *deploy*, the build system automatically deploys the changes.
so usually work is done in various branches, merged into *master* and then, when it's time to *deploy*, *master* is merged into *deploy* and things work.

Since *deploy* doesn't really have anything but regular merges from *master*, I was thinking about trying to use rebase instead of merge.

my understanding is this:

```
git checkout master
git rebase deploy
```

and.. nothing happens

this is the output:

```
$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
$ git rebase deploy
Current branch master is up to date.
```

obviously the feature works and I'm not understanding something :) what am I missing?

maybe this is not the right way to achieve my goal; In short, I'm trying to make it like: head of *deploy* is now pointing to the head of *master*.

Comment: When you say "pushed to deploy" do you mean "merged to deploy"? Repositories get pushed to, branches get merged to.

Comment: Is master directly ahead of deploy? I.e. if you checked out deploy and ran git merge master, would it fast forward?

Comment: @Schwern, yes, I meant merged.

Comment: @JesseLi: yes, it does fast forward.

Comment: "yes, it does fast forward" - and thats, by definition, is the right way to achieve your goal! The only thing that fast forward does is: "head of deploy is now pointing to the head of master".

Comment: ok, I understand, but the fast forward is done through a merge; why is the rebase not working?

Comment: git rebase tries to find the point where the two paths diverged, in order to determine which commits get reapplied. Since the paths don't diverge, there's nothing to rebase - it's already based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `deploy` is never directly committed to and only ever receives merges from `master`...

Just after you've merged a new feature (E - F - G - H) and before you've deployed it, your repo looks something like this.

```
  B - C   E - F - G - H
 /     \ /             \
A ----- D ------------- I [master]
        [deploy]
```

You can use `git log --graph --decorate` to see this structure in your own repository, but flipped vertical.

Note how `deploy` at D is directly behind `master` at I. When you merge master into deploy there's no need for a merge so Git does a "fast-forward" and just moves the `deploy` label to the same commit as `master`.

```
git checkout deploy
git merge master

  B - C   E - F - G - H
 /     \ /             \
A ----- D ------------- I [master] [deploy]
```

`master` and `deploy` now point at the same commit.

When you try to rebase `master` on top of `deploy` the rebase works, but there's nothing to do.

---

As a side note, there's little need for a `deploy` branch in this workflow since `deploy` is always a direct ancestor of `master`. Since you're just moving a label around existing merges it would be simpler to use a tag to mark the commit to deploy.

```
# Move the deploy tag to master.
git tag -f deploy master
```

This also makes undoing deployments much easier. Let's say the latest feature is busted. While you're fixing it you can move the tag back to a previous known good commit.

```
# Roll back deployment to commit ABC123
git tag -f deploy ABC123
```

You can use numbered or timestamped or versioned tags to keep track of releases and release the highest.

```
git tag v1.2.3 master

# Get the newest version
git tag --sort=-v:refname | head -1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the visual explanation, now it is very clear! I also didn't know a tag could be moved, I thought I'd end up with many deploy tags if I went that way, I will definitely try that! thanks!